# Error while trying to print the structure variable-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
-(BOOL)ChangeTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerIds withPeriod:(uint8_t)uPeriod
{
 stRs232Timer*   pEvent;
    NSLog(@"Into the changeTimer");
    NSLog(@"%d",wTimerIds);
    pEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[[m_cAppIdMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]]bytes];
    NSLog(@"bPersistent:%d",pEvent->bPersistent);
    NSLog(@"wAppTimerId:%d",pEvent->wAppTimerId);
    NSLog(@"uPeriod:%d",pEvent->uPeriod);
    NSLog(@"bStopped:%d",pEvent->bStopped);
    //NSLog(@"%@",pEvent);  
    if(pEvent!=nil){
        pEvent->bStopped = NO;
        pEvent->uPeriod = uPeriod;
        NSLog(@"completed");
    }   

    NSLog(@"The dict is:%@",m_cAppIdMap);

    NSLog(@"jsagxs:%@",m_cAppIdMap);
    return YES;
}
```

If i remove the comment in the above code i get an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.Why is it so.

Comment: Did you already set a breakpoint and inspected the value of pEvent? I think, this would help …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the "%@" format specifier, you are telling the runtime to invoke the `-descriptionWithLocale:` or `-description` methods on the associated pointer whose class is implied to be a subclass of `NSObject`.

Structures are not Objective-C objects and therefore do not have a `-descriptionWithLocale:` or `-description` method.
This is what is causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

You should use `%p` for printing out pointers that don't point to Objective-C objects.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me about the cause of error.I got the correct output without any exception.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier %@ works by expecting an `NSObject` subclass, and calling `descriptionWithLocale:` or `description` (if `descriptionWithLocale` is absent) to obtain an `NSString` describing the object. `stRs232Timer` is just a C structure - not an Objective C object. When the runtime tries to treat it as an object things blow up, as you're seeing.

Try the `%p` specifier instead, which will just print the address of the item (i.e. the value of the pointer with a `0x` prefix).

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the cause of the exception.I got output when did as said to do.